# ListView Repeating Last Entry

Tags: android, listview, custom-adapter

i made a listView with custom adapter its getting data from DB and binding it to list view, Adapter Picks number of records very well but it keep showing last record for all entries , for example if there are  5 records retrieved from db the list view will show last record for five time.

here is the code

```
Activities SetAct = new Activities();
final ArrayList<Activities> sData = new ArrayList<Activities>();
try{
    SQLiteDatabase db = openOrCreateDatabase("iTimeDB", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    Cursor c2 = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Activities", null);   // WHERE ID = '" +ID+"'"
    for (c2.moveToFirst(); !c2.isAfterLast(); c2.moveToNext()) {
        String title =c2.getString(c2.getColumnIndex("Title"));
        String details =c2.getString(c2.getColumnIndex("Details"));
        String time =c2.getString(c2.getColumnIndex("Time"));
        String ref= c2.getString(c2.getColumnIndex("Ref"));
        String matter =c2.getString(c2.getColumnIndex("Matter"));
        String date = c2.getString(c2.getColumnIndex("Date"));
        String ID = c2.getString(c2.getColumnIndex("ID"));
        String IMEI1 =  c2.getString(c2.getColumnIndex("IMEI"));
        SetAct.setTitle(title);
        SetAct.setDetails(details);
        SetAct.setMatter(matter);
        SetAct.setRef(ref);
        SetAct.setTime(time);
        SetAct.setDate(date);
        SetAct.setID(ID);
        sData.add(SetAct);
        }
    c2.close();
    db.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.v("YYY", e.toString());
    }
    final ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    listView.setAdapter(new CustomListAdapter(this, sData));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Remove** below line from **outside for** loop **Add** it in **inside for** loop

```
Activities SetAct = new Activities();
```

Example

```
for (c2.moveToFirst(); !c2.isAfterLast(); c2.moveToNext()) {
       Activities SetAct = new Activities();
       String title =c2.getString(c2.getColumnIndex("Title"));
       // Remaining as it is..
}
```